# Arreglo imprime otros valores a los esperados .c

Tags: array, c, funciones, matrices, parametros

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar en C y estoy haciendo un programa en donde se me pide registrar la cantidad de servicios hechos por 5 taxis en un arreglo bidimensional, donde se almacena el código de taxi, clave del cliente, tipo de servicio y el costo, este arreglo bidimensional lo paso a una funcion donde almaceno en un arreglo el total producido de cada taxi, segun su codigo (es decir si es el taxi 1, 2, 3, 4 o 5) y despues este arreglo donde pongo el total producido de cada taxi lo imprimo, pero al momento de imprimir ,imprime otros valores a los esperados, les dejo el codigo y una imagen a lo que imprime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Prototipo de las funciones//
void entradaDatos();
void imprimir(int m[][4],int nfilas);
void totalProducido(int m[][4],int nfilas);

int main(){

entradaDatos();

return 0;
}

//Funciones//

void entradaDatos(){
    int i,j,cant_ser; 

    //Se solicita la cantidad de servicios realizados//
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de servicios\n");
    scanf("%i", &cant_ser);

    int regServicio [cant_ser][c];

    //Ciclo para solicitar el registro de servicios//
    for(i = 0; i < cant_ser; i++){
            j = 0;
            //Se solicita y valida el codigo de taxi//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese el codigo de taxi\n");
                scanf("%i",&regServicio[i][j]);
                if(regServicio[i][j]!= 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03 && regServicio[i][j] != 04 && regServicio[i][j] != 05){
                    printf("El codigo de taxi que ingreso no es valido, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03 && regServicio[i][j] != 04 && regServicio[i][j] != 05);
            j++;
            //Se solicita la clave de cliente//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese la clave de cliente\n");
                scanf("%i",&regServicio[i][j]);
                
                if(regServicio[i][j] < 0){
                    printf("La clave que ingreso no es valida, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] < 0);
            j++;
            //Se solicita el tipo de servicio//
             do{
                printf("Ingrese el tipo de servicio\n");
                scanf("%i", &regServicio[i][j]);

                if(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03){
                    printf("El tipo de servicio que ingreso no es valido vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03);
            j++;
            //Solicita el costo del servicio//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese el costo del servicio\n");
                scanf("%i", &regServicio[i][j]);

                if(regServicio[i][j] <= 0){
                    printf("El costo que ingreso no es valido, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] <= 0);
            
    }
    system("cls");
    imprimir(regServicio,cant_ser);
    totalProducido(regServicio,cant_ser);
}

void imprimir(int m[][4],int nfilas){
    int i;

    //Impresion de los resultados//
    printf("%s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n","== Cliente == ","== Codigo Taxi == ","== Clave Cliente ==","== Tipo servicio ==","== Costo servicio ==");
    for(i = 0; i < nfilas; i++){
        printf("%6i %17i %21i %18i %18i\n", i + 1,m[i][0], m[i][1],m[i][2],m[i][3]);
    }
}

void totalProducido(int m[][4],int nfilas){
    int i, j = 0;
    int total[5];

    //Captura el total producido de cada taxi, segun el codigo del taxi//
    for(i = 0; i < nfilas; i++){
        if(m[i][0] == 1){
            total[0] += m[i][3];
        } else if(m[i][0] == 2){
                total[1] += m[i][3];
                } else if(m[i][0] == 3){
                        total[2] += total[2] + m[i][3];
                        } else if(m[i][0] == 4){
                            total[3] += m[i][3];
                                } else if(m[i][0] == 5){
                                        total[4] += m[i][3];
                                        }
    }

    //Impresion del total producido por cada taxi//
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("El total producido del taxi %i es $%i\n", i + 1, total[i]);
    }
}
```

Esto sale al momento de ejecutar el codigo y por lo que ingrese, deberia salir que solo el taxi 2 genero 45 y los demas deberian estar en 0, no se a que se deba, así que quisiera saber porque sucede esto o como pudiera arreglarlo, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código está bien etructurado en funciones, eso hace más fácil de encontrar y solucionar los errores. El primer problema que encontré en el código fué que no declarastes ni inicializastes la variable 'c' en la función entradaDatos(), la variable debe ser inicializada con el valor de 'c=4', ya que 4 es el número de columnas de tu arreglo.

La otra parte por la que el código no te funciona es porque no inicializastes los valores del arreglo. Al crear un arreglo, los valores dentro de él no son 0, sino que son direcciones en memoria, hasta que se guardan datos dentro de ellos. Por este motivo es que en la suma no te da los resultados esperados, al no estar sumando los valores a un número entero inicial = 0, estos datos son perdidos y mostrados como direcciones en memoria. Por este motivo tienes que establecer todos los valores de tu arreglo total[5] de la función totalProducido, en 0, así: int total[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};. para que despues cada espacio del arreglo te sirva para sumar los datos.

Este es el código completo corregido. Si la respuesta te ha servido de ayuda, por favor márcala como la correcta :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Prototipo de las funciones//
void entradaDatos();
void imprimir(int m[][4],int nfilas);
void totalProducido(int m[][4],int nfilas);

int main(){

entradaDatos();

return 0;
}

//Funciones//

void entradaDatos(){
    int i,j,cant_ser,c=4;

    //Se solicita la cantidad de servicios realizados//
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de servicios\n");
    scanf("%i", &cant_ser);

    int regServicio [cant_ser][c];

    //Ciclo para solicitar el registro de servicios//
    for(i = 0; i < cant_ser; i++){
            j = 0;
            //Se solicita y valida el codigo de taxi//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese el codigo de taxi\n");
                scanf("%i",&regServicio[i][j]);
                if(regServicio[i][j]!= 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03 && regServicio[i][j] != 04 && regServicio[i][j] != 05){
                    printf("El codigo de taxi que ingreso no es valido, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03 && regServicio[i][j] != 04 && regServicio[i][j] != 05);
            j++;
            //Se solicita la clave de cliente//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese la clave de cliente\n");
                scanf("%i",&regServicio[i][j]);

                if(regServicio[i][j] < 0){
                    printf("La clave que ingreso no es valida, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] < 0);
            j++;
            //Se solicita el tipo de servicio//
             do{
                printf("Ingrese el tipo de servicio\n");
                scanf("%i", &regServicio[i][j]);

                if(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03){
                    printf("El tipo de servicio que ingreso no es valido vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] != 01 && regServicio[i][j] != 02 && regServicio[i][j] != 03);
            j++;
            //Solicita el costo del servicio//
            do{
                printf("Ingrese el costo del servicio\n");
                scanf("%i", &regServicio[i][j]);

                if(regServicio[i][j] <= 0){
                    printf("El costo que ingreso no es valido, vuelva a intentarlo\n");
                }
            } while(regServicio[i][j] <= 0);

    }
    system("cls");
    imprimir(regServicio,cant_ser);
    totalProducido(regServicio,cant_ser);
}

void imprimir(int m[][4],int nfilas){
    int i;

    //Impresion de los resultados//
    printf("%s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n","== Cliente == ","== Codigo Taxi == ","== Clave Cliente ==","== Tipo servicio ==","== Costo servicio ==");
    for(i = 0; i < nfilas; i++){
        printf("%6i %17i %21i %18i %18i\n", i + 1,m[i][0], m[i][1],m[i][2],m[i][3]);
    }
}

void totalProducido(int m[][4],int nfilas){
    int i, j = 0;
    int total[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

    //Captura el total producido de cada taxi, segun el codigo del taxi//
    for(i = 0; i < nfilas; i++){
        if(m[i][0] == 1){
            total[0] += m[i][3];
        } else if(m[i][0] == 2){
                total[1] += m[i][3];
                } else if(m[i][0] == 3){
                        total[2] += total[2] + m[i][3];
                        } else if(m[i][0] == 4){
                            total[3] += m[i][3];
                                } else if(m[i][0] == 5){
                                        total[4] += m[i][3];
                                        }
    }

    //Impresion del total producido por cada taxi//
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("El total producido del taxi %i es $%i\n", i + 1, total[i]);
    }
}
```